# Cross-Compiling ROS Melodic on RaspberryPi 3B+ Problem

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, raspberry-pi, ros, catkin

After doing some research, I found that there isn't a single "tried-and-true" way of cross-compiling ROS for RaspberryPi. The best I could come up with was downloading `/usr`, `/lib`, and `/opt` from the target device onto my development machine (installed at `$HOME/Projects/TargetResources`), making a CMake Toolchain file, and calling `catkin_make_isolated -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=...`. Though the build process starts, I'm met with an immediate error:

```
$ catkin_make_isolated -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${HOME}/Projects/${MY_PROJ}/RPI3+_Melodic_Toolchain.cmake
CMake Error at ${HOME}/Projects/TargetResources/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/assert.cmake:17 (message):
Assertion failed: check for file existence, but filename
  (RT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND) unset.  Message: RT Library

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  ${HOME}/Projects/TargetResources/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake:42 (assert_file_exists)
  ${HOME}/Projects/TargetResources/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:159 (include)
  ${HOME}/Projects/TargetResources/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

After doing some digging, the target device (i.e., RaspberryPi 3+) does not have `librt.so`. Interestingly enough, if I just run `catkin_make` for the project on the device, everything builds successfully. So I don't think attempting to install it is really necessary (or the right solution).

Additionally, I should note that the target has ROS Melodic Base installed whereas my development machine has ROS Melodic Desktop installed. I'm not sure if this would cause the issue I'm experiencing, but I don't want to prematurely rule it out.

So, my question is how should I proceed? Did I overlook something whilst setting up the toolchain or am I assuming something about ROS/Catkin that is false?

Thank you in advance for all of your help and consideration.

**Edit / Addendum**

As requested, here is the toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   $ENV{HOME}/Projects/RpiDevTools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/Projects/RpiDevTools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/Projects/RpiDevTools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

In `sysroot`, I copied the RaspberryPi's `/opt` directory as that's where ROS Melodic libraries are installed. I've found that those libraries may have dependencies (for example `log4cxx/level.h`) which are not found in the RaspberryPi/Tools `sysroot/usr/include` directory. Likewise, resolving the shared object dependencies are equally cumbersome.

Comment: Don't you have `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so` ? It comes from the package `libc6-dev` on my RPi 3 (`dpkg -S /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so`)

Comment: Thank you for the full path! `find ${HOME}/Projects/TargetResources/lib -f librt.so` returned nothing, but when I navigated down into that directory, I found that all I have is a soft link of `librt.so.1 -> librt-2.24.so`. I might just need to add the additional soft-link.

Comment: It should works as this is what I have: https://pastebin.com/raw/bxaeZjjQ

Comment: I did some digging, and failed to notice the extra `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so` argument to your listing. Yes, I have what you have except with v2.24 (see [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/x04Livus)). The soft-link work around isn't working for me. I'm also trying to look into the cross-compile tools. If it's supposed to be part of `libc6`, there's a chance that the RaspberryPi Development Tools library  I grabbed from git-hub isn't referencing its own libraries?

Comment: Without seeing the `RPI3+_Melodic_Toolchain.cmake` file it's difficult to say. Add it in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue stems from the cross-compilation tools itself: using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` & `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools means that the compilers are configured with libc libraries in a pre-known configuration. For example, `math.h` includes `bits/math-vector.h`; in the RaspberryPi Tools from GitHub, this is located at `.../sysroot/usr/include/bits` whereas copied straight from the RaspberryPi 3B+ itself is located at `/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabf/bits`. The respective compilers (native and cross-compile) were built with those their respective configurations, but not the others and does not search (well) the generalized paths.